# Scratch org with Knowledge and External objects

Tags: salesforcedx, knowledge, externalobjects

I'm having issues creating a Scratch Org with both Knowledge and External Objects enabled.

It looks like Knowledge can only work in `Enterprise` edition scratch orgs while External Objects/Data sources work only in `Developer` edition scratch orgs.

I've been using the following `project-scratch-def.json`:

```
  "orgName": "Test Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities", "ServiceCloud", "Sites", "Knowledge", "LightningServiceConsole", "LiveAgent", "PersonAccounts", "RecordTypes", "PlatformCache"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      "notesReservedPref01": true
    },
    "knowledgeSettings": {
      "enableKnowledge": true,
      "enableLightningKnowledge": true
    },
    "liveAgentSettings": {
        "enableLiveAgent": true
    },
    "omniChannelSettings": {
        "enableOmniChannel": true
    }
  }
}
```

When I create a scratch org from the above definition file, I can't find `Knowledge` in setup.

When I change the `edition` to `Enterprise`, I can find `Knowledge`. However, pushing our custom data source provider classes result in errors like: 
`Type is not visible: DataSource.Filter`

Help please?

Comment: Does your user account have the Knowledge User box ticked?

Comment: Interesting! Confirmed that creating a Dev org with that config leaves the default user w/o Knowledge User checked, and that checking it exposes Knowledge in Setup.

Comment: Now that is very interesting!

Comment: @ThomasTaylor David Reed, I'm happy to accept "manually setting up the default user as knowledge user" if one of you marks that as an answer. I think it's an issue and will raise it with Salesforce meanwhile. Cheers.